# errors from numberOfRowsInSection function between two TableViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm making a View which is including two tableviews, one of which is the self.tableView and the other one is searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView to display the search result. The code is below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResultArray count];
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView){
        return [menuItems count];
    } }
```

The problem is that I knew the return [menuItems count] value is 10, and if the return value of [searchResultArray count] is bigger than 10, I will get the error message below:

```
2012-09-26 17:11:50.332 searchResultArray count：80
2012-09-26 17:11:50.337 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
```

But if the return value of [searchResultArray count] is smaller than 10, it works fine. How to fix this? 
Please Advise! Thanks!

Comment: what exactly method crashes? it looks like problem is not in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I think in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are trying to display the content of `menuItems` array for `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` . Make sure you are checking the `tableView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and display content for the table from proper array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make sure both of the tableviews are set as "Dynamic Prototypes"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using interface-builder check for TableViewController

There should be a "table view" under your view controller.

in the attribute inspector of the table view Check the "content" , if its assigned "Dynamic Prototypes" or "static cell"?

Change it to "Dynamic Prototypes" .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your search method, each time you run the search logic and add the objects into searchArray- you need to clear the objects from it before it starts adding. You can use

```
[searchResultArray removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

as iMeMyself said you should assigned dynamic prototypes to both tableview. because when datasource method will called it will check the tableview dynamically. so assigned it dynamic prototypes.